# Merged AndroidManifest only contains the Library content

Tags: android, merge, apk, android-manifest

After generating the release build and installing the APK getting the below error,

> Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION: Failed to parse
> /data/app/vmdl1253
> 201057.tmp/base.apk: Corrupt XML binary file]

I have checked APK analyzer in AndroidStudio, and I found that AndroidManifest.xml not contains any code related to my application, it only contains the lib(elepay) permissions and application tag with activities.

Here is my released build merged AndroidManifest.xml file, I copied this from the AndroidStudio's APK analyzer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.allpayx.sdk"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="org.simalliance.openmobileapi.SMARTCARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc.hce" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.allpayx.sdk.activity.AllPayActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <!-- ca渠道配置  begin -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.allpayx.sdk.module.sdk.CAActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <!-- ca渠道配置 end -->


        <!-- wpay sdk begin -->

        <activity
            android:name="com.allpayx.sdk.wxapi.WXPayEntryActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" />

        <activity-alias
            android:name="com.allpayx.sdk.wxapi.WXPayEntryActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:targetActivity="com.allpayx.sdk.wxapi.WXPayEntryActivity" />

        <!-- wpay sdk end -->


        <!-- upay sdk begin -->

        <uses-library
            android:name="org.simalliance.openmobileapi"
            android:required="false" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.unionpay.uppay.PayActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.unionpay.UPPayWapActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|fontScale"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
        </activity>
        <!-- upay sdk end -->

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I tried without this elepay lib and its working, but by using this lib facing the above issue.

Please let me know if you need anything more.

Answer (score 0):

My issue has resolved after upgrade the library version.